# Pushing mysql database changes from local to staging / production

Tags: mysql, git, database-migration

I've played with Laravel and love the database migration system.

I also work a lot with wordpress and wonder if there is a similar way to describe database changes in text files that can be added to git and have those changes push up to a remote version of the db in staging or production environments.

Perhaps the local machine could connect to the remote mysql db and make the changes automatically.

There must be something but i cant find anything through google or other routes.

The closest i've found is http://dbv.vizuina.com/ but im not sure its quite the same thing.

Anyone have any tools or suggestions?

Comment: This is a complex topic and gets difficult to automate beyond simple scenarios. There are lots of products out there at different levels, lots of claims and lots of opinions :) After all my years, we still do it manually. MySQL Workbench can do very good structure diffs for you, you could commit that, then run it on production after doing backups, content migration etc. Trusting a tool to do this... sounds risky to me!

Comment: RedGate is one of the best for MS SQL, although VStudio does it too now. Looking at those might help you find the right product space and terminology to search for a MySQL equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recomend you to use lib https://phinx.org/. We are using this lib in our company and we are quite with that.
You can install this library using composer and configure using php files(is an option - good to include different config files - e.g. from wordpress). The big advantage of this is that you write your migration in php code. You just have to define method up(make migration) and down(to rollback - you can do it to the selected stage). Look at an example below:

```
<?php

use Phinx\Migration\AbstractMigration;

class AddColumnsToVisitorTable extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up()
    {
        $table = $this->table('visitor');
        $table->addColumn('send_at', 'datetime');
        $table->addColumn('visitor_email', 'string');
        $table->addColumn('visitor_source', 'string');
        $table->update();
    }

    public function down()
    {
        $table = $this->table('visitor');
        $table->removeColumn('send_at');
        $table->removeColumn('visitor_email');
        $table->removeColumn('visitor_source');
        $table->update();
    }
}
```

If you merge changes from develop branch to master you also merge migration. After merge we have deploy script which run migrations on live env. so you are sure that with your code you have changed database.

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase's changesets. Doesn't solve problem of rolling back history, bring big headache on merges - but document all data- and structure-changes